# Eigenvectors for matrix products

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, matrix-equations

From "Oscillations" chapter in [Classical mechanics Goldstein](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5nvP_eIBydjYWMwMDhhY2QtNzBmOS00NGM5LWE3NWQtZjFiN2NlNTk3ZTNj/edit)

$A=H^{-1}U$,

then the eigenvalue of A,

$\lambda = \frac{x^{T}Ux}{x^{T}Hx}$

where $x$ is the eigenvector of $A$ and U, H are real symmetric matrices.

If $y$ is the eigenvector of $U$, then what is the relationship between $y$ and $x$?

P.S: I am looking to prove that when the eigenvalues of U increases, corresponding $\lambda $ also increases.

Is it possible to derive a relationship such as $y^{T}Uy=k.x^{T}Ux$? Then I could show that if LHS increases, then RHS also increases.

Comment: You need to specify the relation between $H$ and $U$, otherwise there does not have to be a relation.

Comment: @Chrystomath H and U are not related.

Comment: "P.S: I am looking to prove that when the eigenvalues of $U$ increases, corresponding $\lambda$ also increases." In general it won't. Consider $H = U$, then when an eigenvalue of $U$ increases, the eigenvalue of $A$ stays constant. Even worse, when $H=U^2$, the eigenvalues of $A$ will be the inverse of the eigenvalues of $U$.

Comment: @Florian, In general, it may not follow. However, what constraints could lead to such a relationship? I am getting such a result from values, but a mathematical proof is what I am looking for. What assumptions for the matrices can make it true?